# When should you use npm install vs npm i

Tags: npm, module, command-line-interface

Looking at npm's [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), 'i' is an alias of 'install', would there be any circumstances where it is preferable to use the full 'npm install'?

Comment: It is only shortcut for lazy developers.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is no specific difference between the two. It's just a lazy shortcut.